# ¿Como puedo sacar este Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito saber si se puede hacer un query que tenga como resultado los proveedores que tengan mayor calificación y que tengan asociado uno o mas productos que necesito, en este caso esos productos se le mandan como "parámetros", osea que solo necesito los id de los productos.

Estas son mis tablas de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo lo que creo es un avance, pero nose que mas falte:

```
SELECT
    p.nombre AS partner,
    p.calificacion AS calificacion,
    php.producto_id AS idProducto,
    php.precio AS precio
FROM
    proveedor_has_producto php
INNER JOIN proveedor p ON
    php.proveedor_id = p.id
WHERE
    php.producto_id IN (11, 9, 7)
GROUP BY
    idProducto
ORDER BY
    calificacion DESC
```

Donde '11 ,9 ,7' son los id de los productos que estoy buscando, pero este query solo me trae los proveedores que tienen el producto, pero tampoco toma en cuenta el valor de la calificación del proveedor

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Versión del servidor:         5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
-- SO del servidor:              Linux
-- HeidiSQL Versión:             10.3.0.5771
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;


-- Volcando estructura de base de datos para prueba_PP
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `prueba_PP`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba_PP` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `prueba_PP`;

-- Volcando estructura para tabla prueba_PP.producto
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `producto` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marca` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codigo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Volcando datos para la tabla prueba_PP.producto: ~10 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `producto` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `producto` (`id`, `nombre`, `marca`, `codigo`) VALUES
    (1, 'NARANJA', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (2, 'MELON', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (3, 'SANDIA', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (4, 'UVA', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (5, 'PERA', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (6, 'MANZANA', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (7, 'FRESA', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (8, 'COCO', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (9, 'PIÑA', 'FRUIT', '100'),
    (10, 'DURAZNO', 'FRUIT', '100');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `producto` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Volcando estructura para tabla prueba_PP.proveedor
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proveedor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calificacion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Volcando datos para la tabla prueba_PP.proveedor: ~21 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `proveedor` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `proveedor` (`id`, `nombre`, `calificacion`) VALUES
    (1, 'JUAN', 45),
    (2, 'PERDO', 55),
    (3, 'MARIO', 32),
    (4, 'LUCIA', 36),
    (5, 'JULIO', 78),
    (6, 'LISA', 24),
    (7, 'BOB', 62),
    (8, 'PEPE', 75),
    (9, 'JOSE', 25),
    (10, 'JOAQUIN', 78),
    (11, 'MARIA', 68),
    (12, 'LUIS', 45),
    (13, 'FERNANDO', 85),
    (14, 'MANUEL', 35),
    (15, 'CARLOS', 47),
    (16, 'JOEL', 85),
    (17, 'ENRIQUE', 74),
    (18, 'PABLO', 25),
    (19, 'LULU', 85),
    (20, 'LINDA', 86),
    (21, 'SOFIA', 75);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `proveedor` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Volcando estructura para tabla prueba_PP.proveedor_has_producto
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proveedor_has_producto` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `proveedor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `producto_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_proveedores_has_producto_producto1_idx` (`producto_id`),
  KEY `fk_proveedores_has_producto_proveedores_idx` (`proveedor_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_proveedores_has_producto_producto1` FOREIGN KEY (`producto_id`) REFERENCES `producto` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_proveedores_has_producto_proveedores` FOREIGN KEY (`proveedor_id`) REFERENCES `proveedor` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Volcando datos para la tabla prueba_PP.proveedor_has_producto: ~51 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `proveedor_has_producto` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `proveedor_has_producto` (`id`, `proveedor_id`, `producto_id`, `precio`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, '23'),
    (2, 2, 2, '34'),
    (3, 3, 3, '56'),
    (4, 4, 4, '87'),
    (5, 5, 5, '46'),
    (6, 6, 6, '47'),
    (7, 7, 7, '34'),
    (8, 8, 8, '56'),
    (9, 9, 9, '6'),
    (10, 10, 10, '45'),
    (11, 11, 1, '6'),
    (12, 12, 2, '34'),
    (13, 13, 3, '57'),
    (14, 14, 4, '34'),
    (15, 15, 5, '67'),
    (16, 1, 6, '34'),
    (17, 2, 7, '68'),
    (18, 3, 8, '67'),
    (19, 4, 9, '56'),
    (20, 5, 10, '78'),
    (21, 6, 1, '56'),
    (22, 7, 2, '45'),
    (23, 8, 3, '34'),
    (24, 9, 4, '76'),
    (25, 10, 5, '54'),
    (26, 11, 6, '57'),
    (27, 12, 7, '34'),
    (28, 13, 8, '23'),
    (29, 14, 9, '65'),
    (30, 15, 10, '23'),
    (31, 1, 3, '12'),
    (32, 2, 4, '23'),
    (33, 3, 5, '31'),
    (34, 4, 6, '23'),
    (35, 5, 7, '12'),
    (36, 6, 8, '21'),
    (37, 7, 9, '43'),
    (38, 8, 10, '23'),
    (39, 9, 1, '54'),
    (40, 10, 2, '12'),
    (41, 11, 3, '43'),
    (42, 12, 4, '24'),
    (43, 13, 5, '12'),
    (44, 14, 6, '34'),
    (45, 15, 7, '124'),
    (46, 16, 8, '43'),
    (47, 17, 9, '43'),
    (48, 18, 10, '12'),
    (49, 19, 1, '15'),
    (50, 20, 2, '17'),
    (51, 21, 3, '16');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `proveedor_has_producto` ENABLE KEYS */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: No se ordena por la calificación?

Comment: Se ordena, pero me muestra únicamente los que tienen menor calificación, no los que tienen la mayor, esta va de 0 a 100

Comment: Los proveedores con esos productos (11, 9, 7) tienen calificaciones altas?

Comment: En la tabla PROVEEDORES pueden existir muchos con el mismo producto pero con diferente calificación

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos probar la consulta y dar con la que buscas. Gracias

Comment: Listo, deje una copia de la base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por cómo está redactada la pregunta, no termino de ver justificada la operación de agrupamiento. Ni siquiera que aporte información sobre los productos, pues sólo pides información sobre los proveedores que tengan asociados ciertos productos. Con un par de selecciones lo resuelves de forma más eficiente que con un `JOIN` y un `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM proveedor WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT proveedor_id id
      FROM proveedor_has_producto
      WHERE producto_id IN (11,9,7)
  ) ORDER BY calificacion DESC
  LIMIT 3;
```

Obteniendo como resultado:

> ```
> 5  JULIO   78
> 17 ENRIQUE 74
> 7  BOB     62
> ```

Si necesitas que la consulta te proporcione más información, por favor déjame un comentario para ampliarla.

### Primer comentario

En respuesta a tu comentario, en el que indicas que te gustaría conocer al vendedor con más calificación de cada producto, te sugiero esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT producto_id,MAX(calificacion) calificacion FROM (
        SELECT proveedor_id id,producto_id
          FROM proveedor_has_producto WHERE producto_id IN (1,2)
      ) proveedor_has_producto JOIN proveedor USING(id)
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT proveedor_id id,producto_id
          FROM proveedor_has_producto WHERE producto_id IN (1,2)
      ) proveedor_has_producto JOIN proveedor USING(id)  
  ) c2 USING(producto_id,calificacion);
```

El resultado que obtendrás será:

> ```
> producto_id calificacion id nombre
> 1           85           19 LULU
> 2           86           20 LINDA
> ```

Quedo a tu disposición para cualquier aclaración.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero en realidad lo que quiero de resultado es por ejemplo, si en la parte del 'IN', pongo el id '1' del producto ( IN (1) ), únicamente me debería arrojar el mejor proveedor, en este caso seria solo el proveedor "LULU" que tiene 85 de calificación y si pongo IN (1,2) me debería de marcar "LULU y LINDA" como los mejores proveedores del producto con id 1 y 2. Le agradezco el tiempo

Comment: ¿Quieres al mejor del grupo de productos? ¿O al mejor de cada producto?

Comment: Entendiendo que te refieres a la segunda opción, modifico la respuesta con la query que consigue el restultado que esperas

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas cometiendo dos errores. En primer lugar deberias agrupar por id_proveedor no producto. Y en segundo lugar asegurate de realizar la conversion del campo para obtenerlos ordenados por calificacion.

```
SELECT  id_proveedor, pp.nombr, calificacion, count(id_producto) FROM proveedor_has_producto php
INNER JOIN proveedor pp ON php.id_proveedor = pp.id
WHERE
    php.id_producto IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
    id_proveedor
-- having count(id_producto)>10
ORDER BY
    abs(calificacion) desc
```

Asi obtienes los proveedores con al menos un producto, ordenados de mayor a menor calificacion, y cuantos productos tiene cada proveedor. La linea comentada te permitira agregar una "condicion extra" si quieres obtener los proveedores con un numero determinado de productos.

Si tienes alguna duda, comenta. Saludos.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Necesitas usar una subconsulta que te devuelva el proveedor con la calificacion mas alta y que a la vez coincida con el producto en memoria en ese momento. Creo que esta es una manera sencilla para obtenerlo.

```
select id_producto, prov.nombr, (select proveedor.id from proveedor inner join proveedor_has_producto on proveedor.id = proveedor_has_producto.id_proveedor where id_producto = php.id_producto order by abs(proveedor.calificacion) desc limit 1) b from proveedor_has_producto php
inner join proveedor prov on prov.id = php.id_proveedor
where id_producto in (3)
group by id_producto, b, prov.nombr;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero en realidad lo que quiero de resultado es por ejemplo, si en la parte del 'IN', pongo el id '1' del producto ( IN (1) ), únicamente me debería arrojar el mejor proveedor, en este caso seria solo el proveedor "LULU" que tiene 85 de calificación y si pongo IN (1,2) me debería de marcar "LULU y LINDA" como los mejores proveedores del producto con id 1 y 2. Todo esto con la base que puse en la pregunta. Le agradezco el tiempo

Comment: Entiendo, actualizare la respuesta.